# Trimming image border white space in Java

Tags: java, image, whitespace, pdfbox, crop

Is there any reliable way of cropping surrounding white space from a `PDF` page or a `BufferedImage` in `Java`, ideally using only open source (Apache or MIT licensed) code?

For example, in a PDF document processed page by page, the algorithm would be

1. Detect the rectangle surrounding the non-whitespace content (text, tables, images) for each page.
2. Compare rectangles and chose the largest one (so that all pages/images have a uniform size).
3. Crop everything out of the largest rectangle in each page (all cropped out content should be whitespace).

The main requirement is to reliably implement (3). Operations directly on PDF pages (e.g., using [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/)) or on their [BufferedImage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) counterparts are equally fine.

I have posted a "brute force" answer to that, any improvements most welcome. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brute force answer to the question.

```
public static BufferedImage trim(BufferedImage image, int rgb) {
  int x1 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
  int y1 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
  int x2 = 0;
  int y2 = 0;
  for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); ++x) {
    for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); ++y) {
      if (image.getRGB() != rgb) {
        x1 = Math.min(x1, x);
        y1 = Math.min(y1, y);
        x1 = Math.min(x2, x);
        y2 = Math.min(y2, y);
      }
    }
  }
  WritableRaster raster = image.getRaster().createWritableChild(x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1, 0, 0, null);
  return new BufferedImage(image.getColorModel(), raster, image.getColorModel().isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);
}
```

The solution above is slow because it goes over all pixels. It also assumes that the edges to be trimmed have a uniform color, the value of which is represented by the `rgb` parameter (`-1` for white). Moreover, it "magnifies" the non-trimmed content, since it actually crops the center (non-trimmed) part of the image.